# how to put header and footer in ckeditor

Tags: templates, header, ckeditor, footer

Is it possible to have header and footer with defined template inside ckeditor? For example, i want to have my 'module-name', 'sub-module' in the header. I've been looking for it but have not found any help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I can see the sun shine.

I create my header template in stored procedure  as my default header template with variable like `{company_variable}`. Then, on insert trigger I replace it with my value from table. eg; `@company_name = company_name`

Using `search replace` syntax in trigger to replace and update the `{company_variable}` as depicted below :

```
UPDATE [table_name] SET [column_name] = REPLACE([column_name], '{company_variable}', @company_name) WHERE [column_name] like '%{company_variable}%';
```

The Query above will search for the `{company_variable}` in the `[column_name]` column as a tag to be replaced then replace it with the `@company_name`.

**Example:**
I want to have a simple header like "**TIGOT.CO, Quality is Everything**". So,
`create_header_sp` result a set of HTML header template.
"`<div><strong>{company_variable},Quality is Everything</strong></div>`". Finally, using the code in trigger to replace the `{company_variable}` with the `company_name`